# Approach for creating a hexagonal mesh of line lengths "1" and be able to change specific line lengths and have the other mesh coordinates update

Tags: python, coordinates, mesh

In python, I am attempting to create a hexagonal mesh inside a given polygon.
This I can solve however the problem i am having is that i want to change some of the edge lengths of the hexagons and have the other coordinates update and I'm not sure what approach to use.

To explain better I have here are [some images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm2eq.jpg). The red line is the edge length that is being changed and the hexagons to the right of them are the recalculated coordinates.

Is there some analytical method I can use to achieve this or do i have to resort to coordinate transforms for each hexagon in a matrix of coordinates.

So far i have created a code that can draw a hexagon at any given coordinate using geo-pandas however I am stuck now I need to change lengths, I don't mind starting again if I am on the wrong path by using simple coordinate arrays.

The code below will out put the [last image in this gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm2eq.jpg)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



#what elements to draw lines between
connect = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 1], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6]])

#list of locations to render a hexagon
locations = np.array([[0, 0], [1.5, 1], [3, -1], [4.5, 1], [6, -1], [7.5, 1], [1.5, -2], [1.5, 3], [1.5, -4]])

def connectpoints(xv, yv):
    for i in np.arange(0,len(connect),1):
        pt1 = connect[i][0]
        pt2 = connect[i][1]
        plt.plot([xv[pt1], xv[pt2]], [yv[pt1], yv[pt2]], 'k-')

def coordtransform(hex_loc, size):
    #define origin hexagon geometry and multiply by size
    x=np.array([0, -1., -0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, -0.5]) * size
    y=np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1]) * size
    
    for i in np.arange(0, len(hex_loc), 1):
        newx = x
        newy = y
        newx = newx+hex_loc[i][0]
        newy = newy+hex_loc[i][1]
        plt.plot(newx[0],newy[0], 'ro', markersize = 13)
        connectpoints(newx, newy)



def main():
    coordtransform(locations, 1)
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: For reference, your polygon-consisting-of-six-triangles _started_ as a hexagon, but is no longer a hexagon after deformation. Anyway, it looks like you want to _rotate_ the top-right hexagon as it is attached to one edge of the deformed triangle, and then _deform_ the bottom-right hexagon as it's attached to both an unchanged edge (left), and to a rotated edge (above). Is that right? You need to be specific about exactly what the effect of altering an edge should be.

Comment: Eg. _why_ should the top-right hexagon be rotated instead of deformed? How do you decide rightmost point of the red edge should move when the edge length changes, instead of the left? How do you decide that point belongs to the middle hexagon (which stays still and is deformed) instead of the top-right hexagon? Etc. etc.

Comment: A regular hexagon after deformation simply becomes an irregular hexagon does it not? I am also not sure exactly how the transformations will work, this is what i am hoping to find out. I am wondering the best method to approach this problem.

I need to create some sort of algorithm that will decide whether or not the hexagon will be deformed or rotated etc

Comment: So, you don't actually know what the requirements are yet? If you _only_ move one end (or both ends) of the affected edge and leave everything else the same - will that be sufficient? Will it be sufficient so long as it doesn't end up crossing another edge? If not, why not?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention an important aspect. Each element (edge) is representing a bi-stable element where the energy minima are at  0.8 * L and L. So each edge can either be 0.8 the normal length or its normal length for this model. So I cant have elements conform to whatever shape they want, they have to satisfy the length requirement.

Comment: That information should go in the question, then.